# Make two page navigations on top ang bottom of a list

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm creating a simple PHP page that reads CSV file content and display some selected columns to users **in pages**
Currently, I'm reading each line and display it immediately. Because of this method, I only know total of lines after finishing reading entire file( searching in file also).
What I want is displaying two page navigations on the top and bottom of the list. Like this:

Page 1|2|3|4

---

### Field 1|Field 2|Field 3|Field 4|Field 5....|Field n

Row1

Row2

....

Rown

---

Page 1|2|3|4

After displaying all rows, bottom page nav, I used jquery function: insertBefore to insert another page navi to the top.

Problems are:

1) Top page nav not displayed in IE8 but displayed ater pressing F5(worked in FF, Chrome).

2) Using insertBefore function, the top page nav is suddenly poppep up afer displaying the bottom one. It doesn't look naturally

Any suggestion?

SOURCE CODE:

To make it simple, I rewrite these two simple source files.
-FileList.php: list all csv files
-DisplayInList.php: Display CSV file content

BY THE WAY: I already solved the problem by changing the jquery code in the FileList.php

```
            FileList.php
            <?php
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
                    echo "$(document).ready(function(){\n";
                    echo "$('a[name=dlink]').click(function(e) {\n";
                    echo "    e.preventDefault();\n";
                    echo "    var href = $(this).attr('href');\n";
                    echo "    $.post('DisplayInList.php',{href:href}, function(response)\n";
                    echo "     list_window = window.open()\n";
                    echo "     list_window.document.write(response);\n";
                    echo "     list_window.focus();\n";
                    echo "     list_window.document.close();\n";
                    echo "    });\n";
                    echo " });\n";
                    echo "});\n";
                    echo "</script>\n";


                    //add CSV file link here
                    foreach($file_list as $f){
                        $display_name = "WHATEVER";
                        echo "<TR><TD><a name=\"dlink\" href=",pathinfo($f,PATHINFO_FILENAME),">",$disp_name,"</a></TD>\n";
                    }
            ?>

            DisplayInList.php

            <?php
                echo "<div id=\"paging_tag\"></div>\n";
                if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE){
                    $display_cnt = 0;
                    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
                        $found = {Check search conditions};
                        if ( $found == true ){
                            $display_cnt++;
                            //Display line to client
                            echo "Selected fields of a csv line to user";
                        }
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }

                if ( $display_cnt > 0 ){
                    echo "<p id=\"paging\"><span>PREVIOUS</span> Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3<span>NEXT</span></p>";
                }

                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
                echo "$('#paging')\n";
                echo "          .insertBefore('#paging_tag');\n";
                echo "</script>";
            ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added the sample original code. And solved the problem by changing: [echo "<TR><TD><a name=\"dlink\" href=",pathinfo($f,PATHINFO_FILENAME),">",$disp_name,"</a></TD>\n";] to using <form action="DisplayInList.php"> with hidden field to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Using js for forming up UI is the least priority method. Avoid using javascript whenever it is possible to use serverside and HTML/CSS methods.

I suggest using PHP, for example:

```
$pagerHtml = 'do some code here';
print $pagerHtml; //the first place on top
/*
...
output HTML between the two pager lines
...
*/
print $pagerHtml //the bottom pager line
```

Comment: Thanks. But sorry for my poor explanation. I actually used PHP. I added the original sample code. Btw, I already solved the problem